# Radix sort explanation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity, radix

Based on this radix sort article http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/ I'm struggling to understand what is being explained in terms of the time complexity of certain methods in the sort.

From the link:

Let there be d digits in input integers. Radix Sort takes O(d*(n+b)) time where b is the base for representing numbers, for example, for decimal system, b is 10. What is the value of d? If k is the maximum possible value, then d would be O(log_b(k)). So overall time complexity is O((n+b)*logb(k)). Which looks more than the time complexity of comparison based sorting algorithms for a large k. Let us first limit k. Let k≤nc where c is a constant. In that case, the complexity becomes O(nlogb(n)).

So I do understand that the sort takes O(d*n) since there are d digits therefore d passes, and you have to process all n elements, but I lost it from there. A simple explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: There is a nice explanation in this Quora answer: http://qr.ae/0pyTm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming we use bucket sort for the sorting on each digit: for each digit `(d)`, we process all numbers `(n)`, placing them in buckets for all possible values a digit may have `(b)`.

We then need to process all the buckets, recreating the original list. Placing all items in the buckets takes `O(n)` time, recreating the list from all the buckets takes `O(n + b)` time (we have to iterate over all buckets and all elements inside them), and we do this for all digits, giving a running time of `O(d * (n + b))`.

This is *only* linear if `d` is a constant and `b` is not asymptotically larger than `n`. So indeed, if you have numbers of `log n` bits, it will take `O(n log n)` time.

Comment: Your expalantion doesn't take into account the base of the numbers being sorted, or the width of the largest number, both of which determine the final running time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes it does, `b` is the number of values a digit can have (aka the base) and `d` is the number of digits in each number (aka the width).